# How to stream H263p to linphone using oRTP

Tags: rtp, ivr, linphone

I have my own media stack which uses oRTP.It works fine for audio using
ulaw.I am integrating video support into it.I am trying to use oRTP to stream H.263-1998 videos in a call.I am able to negotiate sip-session successfully.When I dial from
linphone into my media stack,the video window appears but it is blank,nothing displays on it.If i capture stream using wireshark,it plays fine.

I also compared wireshark output of succesfully streamed h263p video with my media stack's. It doesn't give any difference in header and payload and also in packet size. it also shows all properties are same only difference in **"skew clock, max delta, max jitter"**. Can someone please help me on what am I missing here?

Please Let me know if any more details are required.

Thnaks,
Amar

Answer (score 0):

Linphone does not support H.263-1998. It only supports H.264 and if you compile it yourself, it also supports VP8 and Mpeg4. The list on [Linphone's website](http://www.linphone.org/eng/features/) is not correct.

Comment: is it possible to add h263 codec into existing source of linphone iOS code?

Comment: @PraveenKumar No idea, it's been a while since I worked with Linphone, it might be updated by now. I'm working with [webrtc](http://www.webrtc.org/) now, it might work for you, depending on what you want.